# Overloading to support multiple related types (especially pointers)

Tags: c++, overload, parameters

## Problem

I was just trying to debug a set of file-manipulation routines I wrote for a program I am working on. One of them kept returning an `INVALID_HANDLE` error.

## Explanation

I figured out what the problem was. It turns out that because I provided several overloads so that I could call the function with either a file handle or filename, I ended up creating ambiguous overloads.

For example (not variadic functions; the ellipses are just for simplification purposes):

```
INT CopyFileSection ( HANDLE fIn, HANDLE fOut, … );
INT CopyFileSection ( HANDLE fIn, TCHAR* fOut, … );
INT CopyFileSection ( TCHAR* fIn, HANDLE fOut, … );
INT CopyFileSection ( TCHAR* fIn, TCHAR* fOut, … );
```

The first one (`HANDLE, HANDLE`) does the main work while the others just open the file pointed to by the filename and call the first function.

The problem is that a `HANDLE` is just a pointer, so the compile can’t figure out which one I am calling (even though to me it was obvious), and ends up calling `HANDLE, HANDLE` even when I pass a pointer to a string, so naturally it fails since the pointer is not a file handle.

## Question

I want to provide maximum flexibility, so short of re-writing to use `std::string` *instead of* `TCHAR*` for the filenames (which I actually did include as well), what suggestions are there to deal with this sort of scenario?

## Related

As a related side note—a separate question?—I was wondering about the ease, safety, and feasibility of providing overloads for all (or at least a set of) possible permutations.

For example, with a function that takes two files, you could use `HANDLE`, `TCHAR*`, and `string` (probably others, but in this case we’ll stick with these three). This means there are up to nine overloads just for the files: `HH, HT, HS, TH, TT, TS, SH, ST, SS`. Let alone if there are other arguments that could provide more overloads. Surely there must be a better way to both provide flexibility in calling the function and clean, understandable, and maintainable code.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to limit the combinatorial explosion of your overloads is to introduce a small helper class that can accept all the various types and convert them to a single common type.

For example

```
class FileHelper {
public:
    FileHelper(HANDLE& h) : handle(h) {}
    FileHelper(const TCHAR* fName) : handle(openFile(fName) {}
    FileHelper(const std::string& fName) : handle(openFile(fName) {}

    HANDLE getHandle() const { return handle; }
private:
    HANDLE handle;
}

INT CopyFileSection ( FileHelper fIn, FileHelper fOut, … );
```

There is only one overload of `CopyFileSection` and that overload takes two `FileHelper` instances as stand-ins for a pair of file handles. The `FileHelper` class takes care of accepting the different possibilities (existing handle, file name, etc.) and obtaining a file handle for each of them.

Note that the first `FileHelper` constructor takes a non-const `HANDLE` reference. This was done deliberately to inhibit conversions from types that could be converted implicitly to a `HANDLE`, such as (other) pointer types. This has the side-effect that you also can't pass directly handles that were returned by a function, but they need to be stored in a variable first.

Comment: Interesting idea. Your helper class idea sounds like it could indeed help mitigate the permutation issue, and thanks for mentioning implicit conversions; that might be the key to the immediate problem. I’ll give it a shot on Monday.

Comment: Implicit conversions is, with almost 100% certainty your immediate problem